# Print all substrings of a regex

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, string, printing

I am trying to print all the substrings that I find in a text. The problem is that findall() doesn't send back substrings, but match captures like ('H','dog'). I want it to send back a string, for example "Her dog eats"

```
text = open("text_file_thing.txt", "r")
regex_string = "(H|h)er\s+(dog|cat|bird)\s+\w+"
regex = re.compile(regex_string)
match_array = regex.findall(text.read())
print(match_array)
```

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am assuming `text` is a multiline file? And do you want to return the entire line when a match occurs?

Comment: Once the regex matches and consumes a portion of the text, it won't revisit it.

Comment: @PyPingu I only want the substring, not the entire line. And it is a multiline file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [re.finditer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.finditer) instead.

```
import re

text = "Her dog eats. Her bird eats."
regex_string = "(H|h)er\s+(dog|cat|bird)\s+\w+"
regex = re.compile(regex_string)
for x in regex.finditer(text):
    print(x)
```

Gives:

```
<re.Match object; span=(0, 12), match='Her dog eats'>
<re.Match object; span=(14, 27), match='Her bird eats'>
```

Answer (score 0):

OK so I think that the issue is you use `findall` which just returns tuples of the matched parts. 
If you use `finditer` you can get the entire match objects.

Try this:

```
import re
text = open("text_file_thing.txt", "r")
regex_string = "(H|h)er\s+(dog|cat|bird)\s+\w+"
regex = re.compile(regex_string)
match_array = regex.finditer(text.read())

# Now you can either just loop through the iterator or
# convert it to a list if you need to keep the objects and not 
# just print them
match_list = list(match_array)

for m in match_list:
    print(m.string)
```

Answer (score 0):

You define capturing groups. Use non capturing groups to get the whole match:

```
import re

text = """Her pig groans
Her    dog swoons.
her bird feeds.
Her cat purrs."""
regex_string = "(?:H|h)er\s+(?:dog|cat|bird)\s+\w+"
regex = re.compile(regex_string)
match_array = regex.findall(text)
print(match_array)
```

Output:

```
['Her    dog swoons', 'her bird feeds', 'Her cat purrs']
```

See:

[re documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html):

> `(?:...)`: A non-capturing version of regular parentheses. Matches
>   whatever regular expression is inside the parentheses, but the
>   substring matched by the group cannot be retrieved after performing a
>   match or referenced later in the pattern.